# Delete Files Which MD5's listed In Text File - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of MD5 hash of files stored in a text file. And I want delete them all when it been found on system or a path. But I have problem to code it. I have tried to but it only scan one file from listed MD5 so its not what i needed. Is there any way to find them and deleted files which there MD5 hash's are listed in a path. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the code that you've written so far in your question. If you don't, we can't help you.

Comment: I have added the code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

pidgin pseudocode:

```
put md5s in array
cycle through a filesystem
    for each file, put into varable, compute md5hash of variable
    if md5hash is in array, delete file
```

maybe you should skip swap files and system folders.

Comment: `Return hash_generator("md5", file_name)` do you need hash of file contents (as your post title implies) or md5 of the filename?

Comment: No, I have listed them in a text file. And after scan a file it will display the file hash to insure it. its just for me(User interface). its has nothing do with deleting or finding the file.